# How to make my seeds file Idempotent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my deployment process I am running my seeds file.  I want this to be Idempotent so I can run it multiple times without any issue.

Currently I get PG primary key errors if I run it multiple times.

My seeds pattern looks like this:

```
user = User.create(.....)
user.save!

foo = Foo.create(....)
foo.save!
```

How can I make this Idempotent?

Is this the best way?

```
if( user.exists?(some_column: some_value) )
else
  # do insert here 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try :

```
unless user.find_by(some_column: some_value)
    user.save!
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can make use of [**`first_or_create`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create)

```
User.where(email: "email@gmail.com").first_or_create do |user|
  user.name = "John"
end
```

This will only create `User` with `email = "email@gmail.com"` if it doesn't exist or it will return you the instance of existing `User`.

This way you can avoid the `Unique Key Violation`